# How to keep values array in a function static?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I read across stackoverflow that in order to keep an array in a function static, we just need to include the function protype/a.k.a *global scope?*

The idea here is that once the user inputs w, a, s or d the box will move, and the board will be reprinted with the moved box.

In this case the board generated a whole new number and I suspect this is also the reason why there have been no changes to the position of the box.

Can I know the right way to keep it static?

Thanks

```
/*Assignment for HIT2080 Intro to Programming */
/*Num-Crash*/
/*Created by: Prince of Potatoes Land*/
/*Date started: Nov 13, 2013*/
/*Date finished: ... , 2013*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define NROW 19
#define NCOL 19

/*function prototype*/
void WelcomeBoard();        /*Function 1*/
void RandomNum(); /* Keeps the numbers static no matter how many times it is called */
void display_marker( int p , int q , char Array[NROW][NCOL] ); /*This is inside RandomNum Function*/
void MoveNum(  int a, int b, char input );

int main()
{
    /*Function caller*/
    WelcomeBoard();
    RandomNum();

    char input;
    printf("\nw,a,s,d to move");
    input = getch();

    int a = 9;
    int b = 9;

    MoveNum(  a,  b,  input );
    RandomNum();
}

/*function 1*/
void WelcomeBoard()
{
    /*local variable to get the user name*/
    char name[20];

    printf("*****************************WELCOME*****************************\n");
    printf("***************************NUMBER CRASH***************************\n\n");

    printf("Please key in your name: ");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("***Good day %s, let's start a new game... all the best!!!***\n\n",name);
}

/*function 2*/
void RandomNum()
{
    /*Local variable*/
    char Array[NROW][NCOL];
    int x,y,r,c; /*for loop use*/
    int p=9,q=9; /*for indicator used*/

    srand( (unsigned) time(NULL)); /*generate different seed random number everytime*/

    /*assign randon number to odd number in array*/
    for(r=0; r<NROW; r++)
    {
        for(c=0; c<NCOL; c++)
        {
            if (c%2 != 0 && r%2 != 0) /*print number in odd number*/
            {
                do
                {
                    Array[r][c]= rand()%8 +50; /*assign randum number 2 - 9 in array*/

                } while( (Array[r][c] == Array[r+2][c]) && (Array[r][c] == Array[r+4][c] && (Array[r+2][c] == Array[r+4][c])) || (Array[r][c] == Array[r][c+2]) && (Array[r][c] == Array[r][c+4]) && (Array[r][c+2] == Array[r][c+4]));
            }
            /*check either is 3 adjecent when first print*/
            else
            {
            Array[r][c]= ' '; /*for even number to print a space*/
            }
        }
    }

    display_marker( p, q, Array );

    /*print the array*/
    for(x=0; x<NROW; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<NCOL; y++)
        {
            printf(" %c ", Array[x][y]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

/*display_marker function*/
void display_marker( int p, int q, char Array[NROW][NCOL] )
{
    /*assign indicator to cover the middle number*/
    Array[p][q-1] = '|';
    Array[p][q+1] = '|';
    Array[p-1][q] = '-';
    Array[p+1][q] = '-';
}

/*move number function*/
void MoveNum( int p, int q, char userInput )
{
    if ( userInput == 'w' )
        p =- 2;
    else if ( userInput == 'a' )
        q =- 2;
    else if ( userInput == 's' )
        p =+ 2;
    else if ( userInput == 'd' )
        q =+ 2;
    else
        printf("\nwrong Input. Please try again");
}
```

Comment: there is no need for your array to be static (however if you must you can make it global and use the _static_ keyword). really you should pass in the array as a parameter from the calling function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the program with some modifications (for an explanation see the end of the answer).
I tested it and it should do what you asked:

```
/*Assignment for HIT2080 Intro to Programming */
/*Num-Crash*/
/*Created by: Prince of Potatoes Land*/
/*Date started: Nov 13, 2013*/
/*Date finished: ... , 2013*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define NROW 19
#define NCOL 19

/*function prototype*/
void WelcomeBoard();        /*Function 1*/
void RandomNum(); /* Keeps the numbers static no matter how many times it is called */
void display_marker(char Array[NROW][NCOL] ); /*This is inside RandomNum Function*/
void MoveNum(char input );
void print_array(char Array[NROW][NCOL]);
void delete_prev_marker(char Array[NROW][NCOL]);

static char Array[NROW][NCOL];
static int a = 9;
static int b = 9;

int main()
{

    /*Function caller*/
    WelcomeBoard();

    RandomNum();
    display_marker(Array );
    print_array(Array);

    char input;
    printf("\nw,a,s,d to move");
    input = getch();

    MoveNum(input );
    display_marker(Array ); 
    print_array(Array);

}


/*function 1*/
void WelcomeBoard()
{
    /*local variable to get the user name*/
    char name[20];

    printf("*****************************WELCOME*****************************\n");
    printf("***************************NUMBER CRASH***************************\n\n");

    printf("Please key in your name: ");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("***Good day %s, let's start a new game... all the best!!!***\n\n",name);
}

/*function 2*/
void RandomNum()
{

    int x,y,r,c; /*for loop use*/

    srand( (unsigned) time(NULL)); /*generate different seed random number everytime*/

    /*assign randon number to odd number in array*/
    for(r=0; r<NROW; r++)
    {
        for(c=0; c<NCOL; c++)
        {
            if (c%2 != 0 && r%2 != 0) /*print number in odd number*/
            {
                do
                {
                    Array[r][c]= rand()%8 +50; /*assign randum number 2 - 9 in array*/

                } while( (Array[r][c] == Array[r+2][c]) && (Array[r][c] == Array[r+4][c] && (Array[r+2][c] == Array[r+4][c])) || (Array[r][c] == Array[r][c+2]) && (Array[r][c] == Array[r][c+4]) && (Array[r][c+2] == Array[r][c+4]));
            }
            /*check either is 3 adjecent when first print*/
            else
            {
            Array[r][c]= ' '; /*for even number to print a space*/
            }
        }
    }

}

/*display_marker function*/
void display_marker(char Array[NROW][NCOL] )
{
    /*assign indicator to cover the middle number*/
    Array[a][b-1] = '|';
    Array[a][b+1] = '|';
    Array[a-1][b] = '-';
    Array[a+1][b] = '-';
}

/*move number function*/
void MoveNum(char userInput )
{
    delete_prev_marker(Array);

    if ( userInput == 'w' )
        a -= 2;
    else if ( userInput == 'a' )
        b -= 2;
    else if ( userInput == 's' )
        a += 2;
    else if ( userInput == 'd' )
        b += 2;
    else
        printf("\nwrong Input. Please try again");
}

void print_array(char Array[NROW][NCOL]){
    int x,y;
    for(x=0; x<NROW; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<NCOL; y++)
        {
            printf(" %c ", Array[x][y]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

void delete_prev_marker(char Array[NROW][NCOL]){
    Array[a][b-1] = ' ';
    Array[a][b+1] = ' ';
    Array[a-1][b] = ' ';
    Array[a+1][b] = ' ';
}
```

Some modifications that I made include:

1) as you've probably seen Array has been moved outside main with variables a and b. I've done so (there could be other implementations that are better than mine) because you want array to be accessible by all the functions inside the program and the variables a and b will be too. a and b will keep track of the position of the marker. I've declared them static because this way Array, a and b will be accessible only in the current file.

2) now RandomNum() just fills the array with random numbers (only in odd positions). That's what it's meant to do, nothing else. Before this modification, you gave this function too many things to do.

3) MoveNum had errors inside: p =- 2 is wrong. You should have written p-=2 or p=p-2. This error is repeated for all the user inputs.

4) I've introduced a couple of functions: print_array() that now is a function of its own (and not put inside RandomNum). And delete_prev_marker() that is necessary to delete the previous marker before moving it to the new position. Otherwise you will end up having two markers.

5) last thing to say is that obviously all the functions will not need to have a and b as arguments because now Array, a and b are all global variables.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** it's almost Christmas so I decided to implement your program in the elegant way (that is no global variables). Here's the code:

```
/*Assignment for HIT2080 Intro to Programming */
/*Num-Crash*/
/*Created by: Prince of Potatoes Land*/
/*Date started: Nov 13, 2013*/
/*Date finished: ... , 2013*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define NROW 19
#define NCOL 19

/*function prototype*/
void WelcomeBoard();        /*Function 1*/
void RandomNum(char Array[NROW][NCOL]); /* Keeps the numbers static no matter how many times it is called */
void display_marker(int *a, int *b, char Array[NROW][NCOL] ); /*This is inside RandomNum Function*/
void MoveNum(char input,int *a, int *b, char Array[NROW][NCOL]);
void print_array(char Array[NROW][NCOL]);
void delete_prev_marker(int *a, int *b, char Array[NROW][NCOL]);

int main()
{
    static int a = 9;
    static int b = 9;
    char Array[NROW][NCOL];

    /*Function caller*/
    WelcomeBoard();

    RandomNum(Array);
    display_marker(&a,&b,Array);
    print_array(Array);

    char input;
    printf("\nw,a,s,d to move");
    input = getch();

    MoveNum(input,&a,&b,Array);
    display_marker(&a,&b,Array); 
    print_array(Array);

}


/*function 1*/
void WelcomeBoard()
{
    /*local variable to get the user name*/
    char name[20];

    printf("*****************************WELCOME*****************************\n");
    printf("***************************NUMBER CRASH***************************\n\n");

    printf("Please key in your name: ");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("***Good day %s, let's start a new game... all the best!!!***\n\n",name);
}

/*function 2*/
void RandomNum(char Array[NROW][NCOL])
{

    int x,y,r,c; /*for loop use*/

    srand( (unsigned) time(NULL)); /*generate different seed random number everytime*/

    /*assign randon number to odd number in array*/
    for(r=0; r<NROW; r++)
    {
        for(c=0; c<NCOL; c++)
        {
            if (c%2 != 0 && r%2 != 0) /*print number in odd number*/
            {
                do
                {
                    Array[r][c]= rand()%8 +50; /*assign randum number 2 - 9 in array*/

                } while( (Array[r][c] == Array[r+2][c]) && (Array[r][c] == Array[r+4][c] && (Array[r+2][c] == Array[r+4][c])) || (Array[r][c] == Array[r][c+2]) && (Array[r][c] == Array[r][c+4]) && (Array[r][c+2] == Array[r][c+4]));
            }
            /*check either is 3 adjecent when first print*/
            else
            {
            Array[r][c]= ' '; /*for even number to print a space*/
            }
        }
    }

}

/*display_marker function*/
void display_marker(int *p, int *q, char Array[NROW][NCOL] )
{
    /*assign indicator to cover the middle number*/
    Array[*p][*q-1] = '|';
    Array[*p][*q+1] = '|';
    Array[*p-1][*q] = '-';
    Array[*p+1][*q] = '-';
}

/*move number function*/
void MoveNum(char userInput, int *p, int *q, char Array[NROW][NCOL])
{
    delete_prev_marker(p,q,Array);

    if ( userInput == 'w' )
        *p -= 2;
    else if ( userInput == 'a' )
        *q -= 2;
    else if ( userInput == 's' )
        *p += 2;
    else if ( userInput == 'd' )
        *q += 2;
    else
        printf("\nwrong Input. Please try again");
}

void print_array(char Array[NROW][NCOL]){
    int x,y;
    for(x=0; x<NROW; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<NCOL; y++)
        {
            printf(" %c ", Array[x][y]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

void delete_prev_marker(int *p, int *q, char Array[NROW][NCOL]){
    Array[*p][*q-1] = ' ';
    Array[*p][*q+1] = ' ';
    Array[*p-1][*q] = ' ';
    Array[*p+1][*q] = ' ';
}
```

Obviously there are some changes to the code. First of all Array, a and b are local variables. a and b are static so they'll retain their values. For Array it is not needed to declare it static because when we call a function a pointer to the array will be passed as argument (there's no pass by value for arrays). But as you've probably seen the prototypes of some of the functions now require a pointer to a and a pointer to b. This is necessary because if we had integers (and not pointers to integers) as arguments or our functions then those integers would be passed by value and the marker would never move ('cause we would modify the copy of a and the copy of b). So we have to use pointers. The rest is pretty much the same as the first implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the Christmas present @condorwasabi! You're awesome!! :)))

Answer (score 0):

You question is confusing as `static` is a reversed word in C that concerns how storage is initialized

However, in your case (if I read your question correctly) you need to access the char Array without calling the RandomNum function

To do this move the declaration of the Char Array[NROW][NCOL] to where you have the function prototypes

Then it will be available in all the functions.  Be sure to call RandomNum first to set it up

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to declare the array using the static extension to your variable like this:

```
static char Array[NROW][NCOL];
```

Static automatic variables continue to exist even after the block in which they are defined terminates. Thus, the value of a static variable in a function is retained between repeated function calls to the same function.

The less elegant solution for your problem, is to declare the Array as a global variable, and then avoid the hassle, of cross referencing and passing it.

```
..
char Array[NROW][NCOL];
/*function prototype*/
void WelcomeBoard();  
...
```

But its an ugly working solution. here is more detailed information about static variables.

[http://www.phanderson.com/C/static.html](http://techpreparation.com/c-interview/what-does-static-variable-mean.htm)

http://techpreparation.com/c-interview/what-does-static-variable-mean.htm

Comment: Edit: sometimes it work. Most of the time it doesn't. I'm thinking maybe it's because `char Array[NROW][NCOL]` is the size of the array. Is the random number generated stored in this as well?

Answer (score 0):

> I read across stackoverflow that in order to keep an array in a
>   function static, we just need to include the function protype/a.k.a
>   global scope?

Where did you read this?

Anyway you could declare char Array[NROW][NCOL] global by moving it outside of main.
But, correct me if I'm wrong, even if your array is global (or static) it's going to have different numbers every time RandomNum() is called. In your main you call this function twice: once at the start of main right after WelcomeBoard() and another time at the end of main after the user input. So I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: it is as exactly you said. So how can I go about this?